# Find duplicates in arrays of objects and pick one of them comparing their values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
var array1 = [
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5972dbe185c5a00906fbefa7"),
    "name" : "user1",
    "score" : 2.0
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59994cf90b79bc4e8233ed1d"),
    "name" : "user2",
    "score" : 1.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59880bbaa329573db1180acd"),
    "name" : "user3",
    "score" : 0.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5972fa945ad42b149da788b2"),
    "name" : "user4",
    "score" : 3.0
   }
]

var array2 = [
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5972dbe185c5a00906fbefa7"),
    "name" : "user1",
    "score" : 1.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("599d2d8fe9feeb290c699535"),
    "name" : "user5",
    "score" : 1.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59880bbaa329573db1180acd"),
    "name" : "user3",
    "score" : 3.0
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("8072fa945ad42b149da799cc"),
    "name" : "user8",
    "score" : 2.5
   }
]

array3 = _.unionWith(array1, array2, _.isEqual);
```

I have two Arrays of user objects returned from two different search queries, now there may be possible duplicate user objects, i did removed the duplicates using lodash's ._unionWith function, but i failed to select and return one of the duplicate object by adding another duplicate objects score to the score property of object to be returned.
How can i do this in more efficient way. thanks

Comment: Posting your code would be a good first step.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: oh sorry! as this is my first question, i thought my questions description is enough to be understood.

Comment: what do you mean by *"more efficient way"* which one do you have?

Comment: Yeah your code is not really code but just two arrays. You forgot to post the code where you actually tried to do the thing you are asking us about.

Comment: I can do this by looping through arrays and check do what i want, what i mean by efficiency is to get the desired result with less code and quick algorithm, as their may be thousands of records in each array

Comment: please add `ObjectId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a hash table as reference to the objects and reduce the array.

```js
var array1 = [{ _id: "5972dbe185c5a00906fbefa7", name: "user1", score: 2.0 }, { _id: "59994cf90b79bc4e8233ed1d", name: "user2", score: 1.5 }, { _id: "59880bbaa329573db1180acd", name: "user3", score: 0.5 }, { _id: "5972fa945ad42b149da788b2", name: "user4", score: 3.0 }],
    array2 = [{ _id: "5972dbe185c5a00906fbefa7", name: "user1", score: 1.5 }, { _id: "599d2d8fe9feeb290c699535", name: "user5", score: 1.5 }, { _id: "59880bbaa329573db1180acd", name: "user3", score: 3.0 }, { _id: "8072fa945ad42b149da799cc", name: "user8", score: 2.5 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [array1, array2].reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (o) {
            if (!hash[o._id]) {
                hash[o._id] = o;
                r.push(hash[o._id]);
                return;
            }
            hash[o._id].score += o.score;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

using loops you can do something like this:

```js
var array1 = [
   {
    "_id" : "5972dbe185c5a00906fbefa7",
    "name" : "user1",
    "score" : 2.0
   },
   {
    "_id" : "59994cf90b79bc4e8233ed1d",
    "name" : "user2",
    "score" : 1.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : "59880bbaa329573db1180acd",
    "name" : "user3",
    "score" : 0.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : "5972fa945ad42b149da788b2",
    "name" : "user4",
    "score" : 3.0
   }
]

var array2 = [
   {
    "_id" : "5972dbe185c5a00906fbefa7",
    "name" : "user1",
    "score" : 1.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : "599d2d8fe9feeb290c699535",
    "name" : "user5",
    "score" : 1.5
   },
   {
    "_id" : "59880bbaa329573db1180acd",
    "name" : "user3",
    "score" : 3.0
   },
   {
    "_id" : "8072fa945ad42b149da799cc",
    "name" : "user8",
    "score" : 2.5
   }
]



array1.forEach((item)=>{
  array2.forEach((item2) => {
    if(item._id === item2._id){
      item2.score = item2.score +item.score;//add score from first array dup to second
    }
  
  });   
  });
console.log(array2)
```

now array2 has the score for all duplicates in array1

note: i removed ObjectId to get it to work in snippet